# Count phone number in Column C if only Column A has specific Location

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count how many phone numbers are associated with people who work at a specific location, only. Not all rows have a phone number, but I need the ones that DO have a phone number.

| Location | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Location A | Person A | 123-456-7891 |
| Location B | Person B | 123-456-7892 |
| Location A | Person C | 123-456-7893 |
| Location A | Person D |  |
| Location C | Person E | 123-456-7895 |
| Location C | Person F | 123-456-7896 |
| Location B | Person G | 123-456-7897 |

I have tried to use CountIfs and counta formulas but keep getting errors.

I've tried:

=countifs(A2:A8,"Location A",C2:C8,counta(C2:C8)) but I get back 0.

I get errors when I try different versions of it too.

Answer (score 0):

Use-

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A8,"1340 Ansin",C2:C8,"<>")
```

Or `QUERY()` function like -

```
=QUERY(A2:C,"select count(A) where A='1340 Ansin' and C is not null label count(A) ''",0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can collate the entire list as such using:

```
=BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(z,{z,COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,A:A=z)))}))
```

[image]